# PnP - Sharepoint site members and site Owners

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to pull site 'members' along with 'department details, 'job title' as well as other attributes per site. The results pretty confusing as I'm unable to differentiate between site 'owners','admin', 'members' and 'visitors'. The goal is only to list the site members.

So advise around files or item total's per site would be really helpful, I'm to sure on the best solution, looping Get-PnPList doesn't appear to be working.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Tenant **** -Url $adminSiteUrl

$sites = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed | Select-Object

$results = @()

foreach($site in $sites) {

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site.Url  -Tenant ***

$sitename = $site.Title
$siteurl = $site.Url
$groups = Get-PnPGroup

$userResults = foreach ($group in $groups){

$members = Get-PnPGroupMember -Identity $group.LoginName

    foreach ($member in $members) {
$user = Get-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $member.LoginName

$Data = [PSCustomObject]@{

Name = $sitename
URL = $Siteurl
Owner = $site.Owner
Member = $user.DisplayName
MemberDepartment = $user.'SPS-Department'
MemberJobTitle = $user.Title

                        }
                                                                  
                                         }
$results += $Data }

$results
```